# Little simulation of gravity in JS using canvas

Tags: javascript, simulation

So, I am trying to create a few circles and then I want them to fall down. Here is the code and demo: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fGChQ/) FireBug tells me that the method "move" is not defined for undefined objects, so something must be wrong when I want to create an array of obects. Correct my mistakes and take into consideration that I have just started learning object oriented programming in JS.

Comment: `function move() {
        this.y+=4;
    }`

Comment: I have a example code for your experience. http://genosite.free.fr/canvas/game/grav/
and
http://genosite.free.fr/canvas/game/grav/grav.js Enjoy!

Comment: Awesome! +1 for an awesome demo/example! Looks great!

Comment: many thanks for this demo, It will be very useful for me to gain more knowledge

Comment: This virtual world in 3d shows a good example of gravity in js : http://www.virtual3ds.com/myspace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of creating multiple events, create one event and loop in there:

```
  setInterval(function(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,1000,1000);  //Clear the canvas here
    for (i = 0;i<bubble.length;++i)
    {
      bubble[i].move();
      bubble[i].redraw();
    }
  },32);
```

The problem was a scope problem.
The way you had written it `i` had the value of 10 in all events where they where executing.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/some/fGChQ/16/

Your other problem is that you clear the canvas in your redraw... For every circle.

Comment: This almost works, but destroys all but one circle. The one circle falls correctly.

Comment: @GiovanniB All circles are falling... but in the redraw the canvas was cleared. So it cleared the canvas, drew circle 1, cleared the canvas, drew circle 2.... cleared the canvas and drew circle 10. Then waited for 32 ms until it all started over again.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a [fork](http://jsfiddle.net/zrHuC/1/) of this that addresses the looping issues, there also appears to have been a problem with the clearing of the canvas rectangle that was causing some interference

Answer (score -1):

```
for (i = 0;i<bubble.length - 1; ++i)
{
    console.log(bubble[i].y)
    setInterval(function(){
        bubble[i].move();
        bubble[i].redraw();
    },32);
}
```

bubble.length is 10, array is index 0-9. bubble[10] is undefined, so you can't call the method move on it.

Comment: this creates the same problem

Comment: The less than sign accounts for this already. i++ would be preferable, but the real issue with scope by the looks of it.

Comment: it still doesn't solve my problem, because I want every circle to fall down at the same time